# Passing all the variables in array to another php file

Tags: php

I have 2 pages, signup.php and errors.php in errors.php I have:

```
$signuperrors = array(username, password, repassword, email);
```

and I store errors in this array. I want to use this array on signup.php It is a dumb question probably because I recently started php. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean but session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean session.. It is like a variable but saved in a memory of php server(Apache)

First is declare your session on all of your pages that uses the session variables before html tag(anywhere)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Then start declaring your variables like this

```
$_SESSION["signuperrors"] = array(username, password, repassword, email);
$_SESSION["sample"] = "sample string";
```

Hope this helps

Then you can now access those values to other pages

Sample:

```
print_r($_SESSION["signuperrors"]); 
echo $_SESSION["sample"];
```

Comment: So can I change array values like $_SESSION["username"] = "patato" or is there a spesific way to do it. and getting the spesific value of an array with session.

Comment: you can do just as a regular variable you are using, and if you want to remove or decided not to use a certain session variable, you can use unset( $_SESSION["username"]) or user session_destroy() to remove all sessions..

Answer (score 0):

You should look into https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp.
further reading: https://web.archive.org/web/20080707052007/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Comment: Need answer here instead of only the link because the link can be broken